# How many audio clips can Java handle?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip, mixer

I'm making a game in Java. I want for there to be about 100 different samples and at any given time, 10 samples could be playing. However, for each of these 10 samples, I want to be able to manipulate their volume and pan.

As of right now, I request a line as follows: `new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);`

I do not specify the controls that I need for this line, but it appears that Clips always have `MASTER_GAIN` and `BALANCE` controls.

1. Is this correct?
2. Could I just create an array of 100 clips and preload all of the samples? I don't quite understand if Java's lines correspond with physical lines into a physical mixer or if they are virtualized.
3. If I am limited, then how can I swap samples in and out of lines? Is there a way to do this so that all of my say 100 samples are preloaded? Or, does preloading only help when you already have a line designated?
4. Again, if I am limited, is this the wrong approach?  Should I either: 
   a. use a different programming language, and/or 
   b. combine audio streams manually and put them all through the same line.

Wow, that's a lot of questions.  I didn't find answers in the documentation and I really hope that you guys can help.  Please number your answers 1 to 4. Thank you very much!

Comment: *"Please number your answers 1 to 4"* Please consider asking 4 questions (on 4 separate threads).

Comment: *"How many audio clips can Java handle?"*  My experience suggests there is no hard & fast rule - it depends on the JRE.

Answer (score 3):

1) I do NOT think it is safe to assume there will always be a BALANCE or even a MASTER_GAIN. Maybe there is. My experience with Java Controls for audio was vexing and short. I quickly decided to write my own mixer, and have done so. I'm willing to share this code. It includes basic provisions for handling volume and panning.

Even when they work, the Java Controls have a granularity that is limited by the buffer size being used, and this severely limits how fast you can fade in or out without creating clicks, if you trying to do fades. Setting and holding a single volume is no problem, though.

Another java library (bare bones but vetted by several game programmers at java-gaming.org) is "TinySound" which is available via github. I've looked it over but not used it myself. It also mixes all sounds down to a single output SourceDataLine. I can't recall how volume or panning is handled. He included provisions for ogg/vorbis files.

2) I'm not sure how you are envisioning using Clips work when you mention "Samples". Yes, you can preload an array of 100 Clips. And you would directly play one or another of these Clips on it's own thread (assuming using raw Java instead of an audio-mixing library), then reset them back to frame 0, then play them again. But you can only have one thread playing a given Clip at a time: they do not accommodate concurrent playback. (You can "retrigger" though by stopping a given playback and moving the position back to frame #0 then replaying.)

How long are the Clips? 100 of them could be a LOT of memory. If each is a second long, 100 seconds * 44100 frames per second * 4 bytes per frame = 17,640,000 bytes (almost 18MB just dedicated to RAM for sound!).

I guess, if you know you'll only need a few at a time and you can predict which ones will be needed, you can pre-load those and reuse them. But don't fall into the trap of thinking that Clips are meant to be loaded at the time of playback. If you are doing that, you should use SourceDataLines instead. They start playing back quicker since they don't have to wait until the entire external file has been put into memory (as Clips do). I'd recommend only using a Clip if you plan to reset it to the 0th frame and replay it (or loop it)!

3) Once it is loaded as a Clip, it is basically ready to go, there really isn't an additional stage. There really isn't any intermediate stage between an external file and a Clip in memory that I can think of that might be helpful.

Ah, another thought: You might want to create a thread pool ( = max number of concurrent sounds) and manage that. I don't know at what point the scaling justifies the extra management.

4) It IS possible to run concurrent SourceDataLines in many contexts, which relieves the need for holding the entire file in RAM. In that case, the only thing you can preload are the Strings for the File locations, I think. I may be wrong and you can preload the Files as well, but maybe not. Definitely can't reuse an AudioInputLine! On the plus side, an SDL kicks off pretty quick compared to an UNLOADED Clip.

HOWEVER! There are systems (e.g., some Linux OS) that limit you to a single output, which might be either a Clip or a SourceDataLine. That was the clincher for me when I decided to build my own mixer.

I think if only 8 or 10 tones are playing at one time, you will probably be okay as long as the graphics are not too ambitious (not counting the above mentioned Linux OS situation). You'll have to test it.

I don't know what alternative languages you are considering. Some flavor of C is the only alternative I know of. Most everything else that I know of, except Java, is not low-level or fast enough to handle that much audio processing. But I am only modestly experienced, and do not have a sound engineering background but am self-taught.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Things are going well, and this is quite informative.  :D